# Apply modulo %% operation to a Arrow Dataset column and Filter by result

Tags: r, apache-arrow

When working with large time series data, I often need to down-sample. When working with time index stored as numeric or integer epoch time, it is very simple to sample by minute or day with `time %% 60 == 0L` and `time %% 86400 == 0L`, and with some multiplication and rounding, it's easy to extract data at sub-second sample rates as well.

This is a very contrived example, using the built in `beaver1` dataset, I might use an expression like the following base `data.frame` operation to filter to only measurements that were captured at the top of each hour. This is a very contrived answer,

```r
beaver1[beaver1$time %% 100 == 0,] |> head
#   day time  temp activ
# 3  346  900 36.35     0
# 9  346 1000 36.81     0
# 15 346 1100 36.89     0
# 21 346 1200 36.78     0
# 27 346 1300 36.89     0
# 33 346 1400 36.77     0
```

I would like to do a similar operation on an `arrow::Dataset` object. However, when I attempt to use the modulo operator, I get the error: `Error: !is.null(schema) is not TRUE`.

```
## Write a toy dataset
arrow::write_csv_arrow(beaver1,"beaver1.csv")

DS <- arrow::open_dataset(sources = c("beaver1.csv"),format = "csv")

DS$NewScan()$UseThreads()$Project(
  list(time2 = Expression$field_ref("time") %% 100L,
       day = Expression$field_ref("day"),
       time = Expression$field_ref("time"),
       temp = Expression$field_ref("temp"),
       activ = Expression$field_ref("activ"))
  )$Filter(Expression$field_ref("time2") == 0L)$Finish()$ToTable()|> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  head()

# Error: !is.null(schema) is not TRUE
```

**What is the proper syntax for applying modulo operations with an `Arrow::Dataset`?**

**Can I use new columns defined by a `Project()` operation within a subsequent `Filter()` operation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulo function has been implemented in the Arrow package's dplyr bindings, and so you could do something like:

```r
library(dplyr)
tf <- tempfile()
dir.create(tf)
arrow::write_dataset(beaver1, tf, format = "csv")
arrow::open_dataset(tf, format = "csv") %>%
  filter(time %% 100L == 0L) %>%
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 19 × 4
#>      day  time  temp activ
#>    <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
#>  1   346   900  36.4     0
#>  2   346  1000  36.8     0
#>  3   346  1100  36.9     0
#>  4   346  1200  36.8     0
#>  5   346  1300  36.9     0
#>  6   346  1400  36.8     0
#>  7   346  1500  36.7     0
#>  8   346  1600  36.8     0
#>  9   346  1700  37.0     0
#> 10   346  1800  37.0     0
#> 11   346  1900  37.0     0
#> 12   346  2000  37.1     0
#> 13   346  2100  36.8     0
#> 14   346  2200  37.2     0
#> 15   346  2300  37.2     1
#> 16   347     0  36.9     0
#> 17   347   100  36.8     0
#> 18   347   200  36.9     0
#> 19   347   300  36.9     0
```

Comment: Whoops - looks like you got here just before I finished editing my question to clarify I'm hoping for a direct use of `Expression` objects - this does solve the original problem posed!

Comment: You can use that code snippet without the `collect()` at the end to view the details of the filter, to work backwards to see which of the Arrow compute functions you need to use to get the equivalent of R's `%%`.  Then your question is simplified to "how do I use Arrow compute functions in Expressions" at least.

Comment: Good point - I'd been skimming [`eval_array_expression`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/r/R/arrow-datum.R), and based on the comment _"We can't simply do {e1 - e2 * ( e1 %/% e2 )} since Ops.Array evaluates eagerly, but we can build that up"_, I suspected this might be some technical reasons why `%%` is not as straight-forward as a map compared to other filters like `is_in`. Looks like the other thing I was missing is that the full definition needs to be within the `Filter()` call instead of trying to operate on a `Project()` column?

Comment: You could also try substituting `collect()` for `show_query()`, which we've bound to `arrow::show_exec_plan()`, which gives more information about the ExecPlan created by the dplyr bindings and may or may not help you.